# How to use python argparse with conditionally optional arguments?

Tags: python, conditional-statements, argparse, optional-parameters

Here is the current code.

```
import time
import collections
from modules import outputs
from modules import scrub
from modules import lookups

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='AppMap Converter to Generate Asset Files from AppMapp Data')
parser.add_argument("operation", nargs='?', default="empty", help='The operation to perform')
parser.add_argument("input", nargs='?', default="empty", help='The input AppMapp File Path')
parser.add_argument("output", nargs='?', default="empty", help='The output Asset File Path')
args = parser.parse_args()

start = time.time()

if(args.operation == "Convert"):
    input_file_path = args.input
    output_file_path = args.output
    #DO LOTS OF STUFF
else:
    exit()
```

The script is called sacsproc, so I run it from the command line as follows:

```
./sacsproc Convert input.csv output.csv
```

This all works nicely, the problem is that I need more sacsproc commands which may have a totally different set of secondary parameters. i.e. one command might be:

```
./sacsproc Clean -rts input.csv output.csv err.csv
```

Thus, I am trying to determine **how one defines arguments that are conditional on the first argument**? In my mind, I'm thinking about the zfs command line utilities that do what I am trying to do (e.g. zpool create mirror sdb sdc vs. zpool remove sda).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use subparsers

```
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help="sub-command help")

group1 = subparsers.add_parser("something",help="do something")
group1.set_defaults(which="g1") # some default value (so you know which group was activated)
group1.add_argument("ARG",help='do something on ARG')

group2 = subparsers.add_parser("other",help="do something else")
group2.set_defaults(which="g2") # give some default value
group2.add_argument("ARG",help='do something else on ARG')
```

ok ...

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help="sub-command help")
g1 = subparsers.add_parser("thing1",help="bind to a port and just echo back anything it gets ... with a prompt")
g1.set_defaults(which="g1")
g1.add_argument("input",help='the input file')
g1.add_argument("output",help='the output file')
g2 = subparsers.add_parser("thing2",help="create a bridge between two ports, this is useful for generating a logfile")
g2.set_defaults(which="g2")
g2.add_argument("input",help='thie input file')
g2.add_argument("output",help='the output file')
g2.add_argument("error",help="the err file")


def print_help(args):
    print "ARGS:",args
    try:
        parser.parse_args(args)
    except:
        print "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n"

print_help(["-h"])
print_help(["thing1","-h"])
print_help(["thing2","-h"])
```

Comment: Thanks, points me in the right direction. After testting I think this works, but the help files seem a little wonky: $ ./sacsproc CombineAppMapp --help
usage: sacsproc ConvertAppMapp [-h] [input] [output]

Comment: Moving things around I get (not what I expect): $ ./sacsproc CombineAppMapp --help
usage: sacsproc [operation] ConvertAppMapp [-h] [input] [output]

Comment: I was hoping you could connect the dots yourself, but there is now a more complete example that is exactly what you want i think...